# Does tidal volume have any significance in a pulmonary function test?

Tags: lungs

In a pulmonary function test (PFT) two important parameters are forced vital capacity (FVC), forced expiratory volume in one sec (FEV1). These are useful for diagnosing obstructive and restrictive lung diseases. Then what is the use of tidal volume (VT) in diagnosing lung conditions?

Comment: What does your research indicate?